# MATLAB loading and saving a single image from a 32 bit tiff stack

Tags: matlab, stack, frame, tiff

I'm using MATLAB_R2011a_student. I have some image stacks saved as 32 bit tiffs, some over 1000 frames. I would like to be able to pull out a specific frame from the stack and save it as a 32 bit tiff or some readable format where there would be no data loss from the original. Currently my code looks like this:

```
clear, clc;
k=163;
image=('/Users/me/Filename.tiff');
A = uint8(imread(image, k));
B=A(:,:,1);
J=imadjust(B,stretchlim(B),[]);
imwrite(J,'/Users/me/163.tif','tif');
```

(I'm assuming reading it as 8 bit, and the way I'm saving are not the best way to do this)
Either way this code works for a seemingly random number of frames (for example in one file.tiff the above code works for frames 1-165 but none of the frames after 165, for a different file.tiff the code works for frames 1-8 but none of the frames after 8) I'm also getting a strange horizontal line in the output image when this does work:

??? Error using ==> rtifc
Invalid TIFF image index specified.

Error in ==> readtif at 52
[X, map, details] = rtifc(args);

Error in ==> imread at 443
    [X, map] = feval(fmt_s.read, filename, extraArgs{:});

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand sorry. Which image are you trying to open/save? The 163th? And by stack you mean a multi-tiff file right?

Comment: Yes, in this example I am trying to open the 163rd image and am getting that error message. and by stack I mean it is saved as a single tiff file but is a 3d array that can be separated out into multiple tiffs (when opened in imageJ is opened as a stack).

Comment: so did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The best way (in my opinion) to handle tiff stacks is to use the [Tiff library](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-images.html#br_c8to-1) available since a few years. I must admit that I don't know much about OOP but I managed to understand enough to load a tiff stack and manipulate it.That's the kind of simple demo I wish I had seen a year ago haha.

I the following example I load a single stack and store it all into a 3D array. I use `imfinfo` to fetch infos about the images, notably the number of images/stack and the actual image dimensions. If you want you can choose to load only one image using appropriate indices. Please try the code below and play around with it; you'll understand what I mean.

```
clear
clc

%// Get tiff files you wish to open
hFiles = dir('*.tif');

%// Here I only have 1 multi-tiff file containing 30 images. Hence hInfo is a 30x1 structure.
hInfo = imfinfo(hFiles(1).name);

%// Set parameters.
ImageHeight = hInfo(1).Height; 
ImageWidth = hInfo(1).Width;
SliceNumber = numel(hInfo);

%// Open Tiff object
Stack_TiffObject = Tiff(hFiles.name,'r');

%// Initialize array containing your images.
ImageMatrix = zeros(ImageHeight,ImageWidth,SliceNumber,'uint32');
for k = 1:SliceNumber

    %// Loop through each image
    Stack_TiffObject.setDirectory(k)

    %// Put it in the array
    ImageMatrix(:,:,k) = Stack_TiffObject.read();
end

%// Close the Tiff object
Stack_TiffObject.close
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work a little better than what I had. I still need to use contrast stretching to be able to see anything when I use imtool(). Is there any way to keep it as a 32 bit float, and be able to see or save individual frames/slice numbers as 32 bit floats?

Comment: Good question! I once had a similar issue with uint16 data and the trick was to use `imwrite` as follow: `imwrite(uint8(YourImage/255),...)`; so in the case of uint32 data I suspect the following should work: `imwrite(uint8(YourImage/65535),...);` because it somehow saves as uint8...maybe there's something I don't understand but the above trick worked for me :)

Comment: That's not working for me..I'm getting images of all zero values. So the idea is that we're opening the 32 bit float as a uint16 and saving as an uint8? There wouldn't be data loss in all these steps?

Comment: Also when I try this with certain 32tiffs I get "BigTIFF is not yet supported" or "This is a BigTIFF file.  This
format not supported
by this version of libtiff.." I've looked around and these should be supported.. thoughts?

Comment: Oops I made a typo you can indeed open the images as uint32; I wrote uint16 sorry about that. As for the saving part yes I agree with you; that was the only way I found to open truecolor images in ImageJ. Otherwise, saving as uint16 and not modifying data resulted in ImageJ opening my images as composite and not truecolor. I guess someone knows better than me about this

Comment: you're welcome! Sorry I could not answer all your questions!